# Should I change my MBP 13" early 2014 battery

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I recently checked my battery cycles count: 942, this is very close to the limit 1000 as indicated by Apple https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201585

If it becomes 1000 do I have to replace it by myself?
I checked https://www.ifixit.com/ and I find that the process is a bit complicated. I live in france and the official Apple replacement service would cost me 229€.

Also can I still use the battery after the 1000 limit? Would this have any negative effects on other system components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2010) and the battery cycles counts more that 1100. Maybe I'm lucky, but I never change the battery and I think is working very well. (The System Information report a Condition that is Normal!)

After the 1000 cycles the battery probably start and continue to decrease a bit the *Full Charge Capacity* but you can still use it. The decreasing of the total capacity result in a small duration time of the battery, but anyway you'll not have any negative effects in any system components.